# Mac OS X split csv not working

Tags: macos, csv, split

I am attempting to split a large 200,000 line csv file into smaller pieces using the terminal command:

```
split -l 20000 users.csv
```

From what I have read online this should chop up the 200,000 line csv into ten 20,000 line files but this doesn't happen. All I get is a text file called 'xaa' that is just the original csv, all 200,000 lines.

Like I said in the title I am running on Mac OS High Sierra v.10.13.5

What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: Perhaps the file uses a line ending character that is not being recognized as such, so `split` thinks it's all one line. Probably CR.

Comment: this is not a question about programing, so it doesn't belongs to SO.

Answer (score 4):

As Ken Thomases points out in the comments, the most likely culprit is that the file is using non-newline line separators, and the most likely culprit is CR (carriage return).

You can tell if this is the case using the `file` utility. A file with such line separators looks like this:

```
$ file foo
foo: ASCII text, with CR line terminators
```

The reason `split` would behave this way with those line separators is that the file would appear to be only one line long (no newline characters). So `split` would write that one (very long) line, then exit.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the split command with the -b option. This will split your files based on kilobytes or megabytes. This may break up a line at the end but can manually be accounted for.